# Making particles wander around on a plane

Tags: particles, force-fields

How do I make particles exist on a plane and make them move around on the plane by using a force field?

I want to create something similar to this, but in blender so I can change the properties of the particles:

http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2016/6/23/processing-noise-crawler